# Enable tablet mode on only one screen with multiple displays

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, tablet, windows-11

I have a situation of dual non-touch monitors and a third touchscreen monitor - I recently bought [Luna Display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/) to use my iPad as third display.

I was wondering if I can use tablet mode only for one monitor (the iPad Display) in the multiple monitor setup.

Of note, the iPad shows as a third display monitor in Windows settings.

Comment: I do not believe this is currently a supported feature - you cannot use tablet mode with a multiple display setup, unfortunately.

Comment: You can try SpaceDesk app to use iPAD as Windows external display:
https://www.spacedesk.net/
(upto 4 devices)